# Is " sizeof " Operator really important in Programming especially in building big Apps?

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

**Except these type of programs :**

As in the program we don't know that how many rows are there in the " Array ",
so we get that row box empty. We made our program without knowing the value of 
row.

**Is there any other uses of these " sizeof " Operators ??**

```
int main() {


    string animals[][3] ={
        {"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"},
        {"Lion", "Tiger", "Elephant"}
    };

    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < sizeof(animals) / sizeof (animals[0]); a++) {
        for (unsigned int b = 0; b < sizeof(animals[0]) / sizeof(string); b++) {
            cout << animals[a][b] << " " << flush;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(animals) / sizeof (animals[0])` --> `std::size(animals)`

Comment: FWIW, `sizeof` isn't needed in your exmaple: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eab99455b3f4fcf3

Comment: If you don't know how big something is, you almost always have to find out sooner or later. If you can make the compiler do it for you, see above two comments, bonus

Comment: regardless of big or small programs, you always need to know the size in many cases

Comment: Note that `sizeof` ONLY provides the size of the object itself. If the object references some other data, that is not included. Example, a simple `string` implementation is a pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer and an integer holding the size of the buffer. If  you read War and Peace into a `string WarAndPeace` and then `sizeof(WarAndPeace)`, you'll get something like 16, the size of the pointer and the size of the integer, not the size of the data referenced by the `string`.

Comment: As a professional c++ developer I almost never use `sizeof()`. It's been years since I have used that. I don't use c arrays that often either.

Comment: In this example I would have used a range based for loop.

Comment: My C++ code base is quite large (hundreds of thousands of source files, gigabytes of source code), and I have not run into a `sizeof` yet, and I haven't used one myself yet.  Probably some squirreled away in the VM subsystem.

Comment: Alright at the end i sum up that its not in use that much ,Right????? OR is it useful to learn this kinda stuff in C Except the basic ones

Comment: `sizeof()` is useful if you are programming in `c`. When you finally learn the `c++` language you don't use it that much if at all. I say finally because a lot of university `c++` courses begin by teaching you `c` concepts at first.

Comment: It's not necessary in modern C++ and many consider it good style to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `sizeof` is important.

Can you write "big" apps without it? Well, it depends on what each individual app does, so yes and no. If your app never needs to know the size of an object in bytes or the number of elements in a statically-allocated array, then you probably won't need `sizeof`.

On the other hand, if your app does something like write a bunch of `int`'s to some device or file, then you probably will find `sizeof(int)` rather valuable, because you are likely to need to know how many bytes you are writing.

You may also have an array defined in a header somewhere (and maybe it's not **your** header) and you need to know how many elements are in that array, while guarding against future changes in that array. `sizeof(array)` is what you want.

`sizeof` is there for a reason. It's not just a holdover from C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Large applications frequently use some kind of memory management. The size of objects is important, and `sizeof()` is the definitive way of getting the size of an object (or type).

Comment: There is a better way in this case: `std::size()`. Or just a range based `for` loop.

Comment: @Jesper I think we're trying to answer different questions from each other

Comment: @user4581301, The answer is talking about finding the size of an arbitrary object. `std::size` is for uniformly getting the number of elements in a container or array.